# Searchlight Inefficient Compression Scheme

Tags: python, c++, compression

**Write a compression and decompression algorithm for SICS which works as follows: Find the most popular characters, and in order of popularity assign them a hex value 0 to E, F0 to FE, FF0 to FFE, etc. Note, an F indicates that there are more nibbles to follow, anything else is the terminal nibble.**

Compress the message by replacing characters with their assigned value. Below are the sample text, but the code should work universally for any given text.

Test case:
text = "Marley was dead: to begin with. There is no doubt whatever about that. The register of his burial was signed by the clergyman, the clerk, the undertaker, and the chief mourner. Scrooge signed it: and Scrooge’s name was good upon ’Change, for anything he chose to put his hand to. Old Marley was as dead as a door-nail. Mind! I don’t mean to say that I know, of my own knowledge, what there is particularly dead about a door-nail. I might have been inclined, myself, to regard a coffin-nail as the deadest piece of ironmongery in the trade. But the wisdom of our ancestors is in the simile; and my unhallowed hands shall not disturb it, or the Country’s done for. You will therefore permit me to repeat, emphatically, that Marley was as dead as a door-nail."

solution = "f826b1d0e2a08128fd0340f61f0750e739f50fe916107a054084cf630e9231ff01602f64c303923f5 0fe91061f07a31604f3097a0f6c672b0e2a0a7f05180f6d03910f2b16f0df125f403910f2b16f9f4039 10c581632f916f4025803910f2971f30f14c6516f50ff1f2644f010a7f0518073fd02580ff1f2644f01fa a052f110e2a0f04480cf7450faff2925f01f40f346025d3975f00910f294a10340f7c3097a09258034f 50ff3b80f826b1d0e2a02a0812802a0208446fb527bf50f8758ff40fc0845fa30f11250340a2d03923 0fc0f954ef404f30f1d04e50f954eb18f01f40e92303916107a0f72637f2cb26bd0812802f64c30208 446fb527bf50fc0f17f093092ff010f6115075f2b7518f40f1da1bf3f4034061f0268020f24f3f375fb52 7b02a0391081281a30f771f2104f307645f145f016d0750391036281f50ff5c303910e7a84f104f30 4c6025f21a346a07a07503910a7f17b1ff602580f1d0c592bb4e1809258a0a92bb0543087a3c6f6 073f404603910ff24c536dfaa084510f346f50ff74c0e7bb039161f34610f716f1730f11034061f7123 f401f1f79237f22bbdf4039230f826b1d0e2a02a0812802a0208446fb527bf5

Answer (score 1):

I am adding a code that can help to solve your problem. It will ask for raw input and you can modify it as per your need.

```
from collections import Counter

key = []


def initCompute(data):  # here i am finding the unique chars and its occurrence to find the popular char
    uChar = list(set(data))
    xCount = dict(Counter(data))
    xCount = dict(sorted(xCount.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
    return len(uChar), xCount


def compute(data, keyList, dataDict):  # assigning the hex value(key) to the each characters
    j = 0
    comDict = {}
    decdict = {}
    sol = ""
    for k in dataDict:
        comDict[k] = [keyList[j], dataDict[k]]
        decdict[keyList[j]] = k
        j += 1
    for c in data:
        sol += comDict[c][0]
    return sol, decdict


def decompression(keyDict,
                  cData):  # this is to find the decompressed data by having the dict of 
    # hex value assigned to char and compressed data as inputs 
    sol = ""
    fNib = ""
    for s in cData:
        if s == 'f':
            fNib += s
        else:
            fNib += s
            sol += keyDict[fNib]
            fNib = ""
            # print(sol)
    return sol


def compression():  # find the key(hex value) and framing the compressed data
    i = 0
    fac = 16
    pwr = 1
    keyLen, dDict = initCompute(text)
    while len(key) <= keyLen:
        if i <= (fac - 2):
            key.append(str(hex(i))[2:])  # finding the hex value and storing in key
            i += 1
        else:
            pwr += 1
            fac = pow(16, pwr)
            i = fac - 16
    sol, newDict = compute(text, key, dDict)
    print("Assigned hex values for each character: ")
    print(newDict)
    return sol, newDict, keyLen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = input("Input your Data here: ")  # input
    compressed_data, new_dict, key_len = compression()
    print("Compressed data: ",compressed_data)
    print(compressed_data)
    print("Decompressed data:")
    print(decompression(new_dict, compressed_data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, how about doing the same with Counter